Join 2 strings to get the GitHub action secrets
I have few repository secrets in GitHub action, like
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_DEV, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_UAT, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_STAGE.
I can take the environment values (DEV, UAT and STAGE) from the branch name. But I want to join these 2 string to get the secrets.
I tried with
env:
 BRANCH_NAME: ${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }} 
...
jobs:
  deploy:
   ...
    - name: Configure AWS Credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_'+ env.BRANCH_NAME ] }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_'+ env.BRANCH_NAME] }}

But it is not working.

I found a way from this GitHub Doc
- name: Configure AWS Credentials
  uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
  with:
    aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets[format('{0}_{1}', 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', env.BRANCH_NAME)] }}
    aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets[format('{0}_{1}', 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', env.BRANCH_NAME)] }}


is the format funtion supported within secrets context?? i am not sure

it is supported...!

i dont think github supports you to concatinate string within the 'secrets' context but you make use of run which will open a shell script where you can construct yoru env variables as per your branch and pass it to $GITHUB_ENV file which will help you preserver the variables for the duration of that job as follows:
env:
  BRANCH_NAME: ${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }} 

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set up environment based on branch
        id: set-env
        run: |
          ENV=""
          if [[ "${{ env.BRANCH_NAME }}" == "main" ]]; then
            ENV="PROD"
          elif [[ "${{ env.BRANCH_NAME }}" == "release/"* ]]; then
            ENV="UAT"
          elif [[ "${{ env.BRANCH_NAME }}" == "feature/"* ]]; then
            ENV="DEV"
          else
            ENV="STAGE"
          fi
          echo "ENVIRONMENT=$ENV" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_NAME=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_${ENV}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_NAME=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_${ENV}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets[env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_NAME] }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets[env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_NAME] }}

hope this will resolve your error and help you get the secrets.

there is a function called format to join 2 string. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/choosing-what-your-workflow-does/evaluate-expressions-in-workflows-and-actions#format
